# Small Code Changes to an already existing install4j Installer

Tags: install4j

I need a minimal code change to an existing installer which was built by an external contractor who doesn't work for us anymore. After the installation the installer writes an output file with text the user provides during the installation. One field is missing and I need to obtain the value of the given user input.

I already run tools like `javap` and krakatau and found the parts in the code where the values are written to the file. Is it possible to make changes to the code (I think it is byte code or something else) and put it back in the installer package?

Answer (score 0):

This is generally not possible because changing a single bit in the installer will break the code signature. Also there are no tools that would help you with such a modification.